# SQL Server 2008 - Mix of Int and Decimal Values stored as Varchar(50) Can't Convert To Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two columns of data in a SQL Server 2008 table that I need to convert from `varchar(50)` over to `decimal`. Get different errors depending on the methods I try to use.

1. Error converting data type `varchar` to `numeric`.
2. Arithmetic overflow

Some ways I have tried:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,10),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(value)),',',''),' ',''),'-',''))

CASE 
   WHEN value = 1
      THEN CONVERT(numeric(14,2), value)
   ELSE 'NA'
END
```

Here is a sample of the data in the table that I am trying to convert:

```
271.5
 14.95
352.5
150
 37.5
 20.5
300
 90
```

This shouldn't be this hard...

Comment: Are you sure there are no non numbers in the varchar column? Your sample values seem to convert well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/325ee/2

Comment: SELECT cast(column as decimal(5,2)) from table.Modify the length in case you need more.

Comment: @Joachim - I strongly suspect that at this point. I have been going over each of the columns to scrub them.

Comment: @Mihai - I have tried the cast as a decimal earlier, but will try again once I've assured myself the data is clean. Thanks!

Comment: An easy way to test to see if your code would work if the data were all clean is to simply try your commands on the `top 10` or `top 100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST` should work well as long as the data is clean and the range is sufficient.

If you're not sure that all values are actually numeric, you can scrub them before converting them;

```
SELECT value, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value)=1
              THEN CAST(value AS NUMERIC(10,2))
              END value2
FROM table1
```

This will convert the string `value` to a `NUMERIC` if it is actually convertible, and otherwise give the value `NULL`.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80a3e/3).

Comment: This ended up being the case for me. Added additional checks to the CASE WHEN qualifying statement to assure that other messy data wouldn't slip in.